# Mysql `OR` condition doesn't work with JOIN

Tags: mysql

I am trying to use a `OR` condition joining a few tables but it only works if the user is in the `eventParticipant` table (`eventParticipant = ?`) but the query doesn't return anything if user is the event organizer (`event.user_id = ?`)

```
$query = $this->_db->prepare("SELECT event.event_id,
                                    event.user_id,
                                    event.sport_id,
                                    event.created, 
                                    event.event_date,
                                    event.public,
                                    places.name as event_location, 
                                    places.country, 
                                    places.city,
                                    places.lat,
                                    places.lng,
                                    places.zipCode,
                                    event.description,
                                    event.cost,
                                    event.maxParticipant, 
                                    tennis.fieldType,
                                    tennis.matchType,
                                    sportSupported.sport_name as tableName 
                                    FROM event 
                                    JOIN sportSupported on  event.sport_id = sportSupported.sport_id
                                    JOIN places on  event.place_id = places.place_id
                                    JOIN eventParticipant on eventParticipant.event_id = event.event_id
                                    JOIN tennis on tennis.event_id = event.event_id
                                    WHERE (event.user_id = ? OR eventParticipant.user_id = ?)");

$query->bindParam(1, $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query->bindParam(2, $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);

if ($query->execute()){
    $result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $data["data"] =  $result;
    //....other stuff.....
}
return json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default join type is `INNER`. This requires that the record is found in both tables (e.g. that the user is found in `eventParticipant`). You need the record to be found in one of the tables. For this, you need an `OUTER JOIN` (you can just replace `JOIN eventParticipant` with `LEFT JOIN eventParticipant` which means `left outer join`), so `eventParticipant` table would be joined even if there is no matching record (it will return null for eventParticipant.user_id in that case). Then the `WHERE` will filter the record you need

Comment: *" Then the WHERE will filter the record you need"* iam more tempted to move the  (non `table.column is NULL`) filter condition(s) to the `ON` clause when using outer joins to avoid accidentally getting `INNER JOIN` results.

Comment: changing `JOIN eventParticipant` to `LEFT JOIN eventParticipant` did the trick. Thanks